# Permissions Creating external Impala table

Tags: impala, hue

Good morning,

When trying to create an external table in the Hue Impala query editor I get a permission denied error. Where to do I need to grant the permissions?

The error message:

```
ImpalaRuntimeException: Error making 'createTable' RPC to Hive Metastore: CAUSED BY: MetaException: Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied: user=impala, access=WRITE, inode="/user/ds":ds:ds:drwxr-xr-x at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:279)
```

Here's the command that fails:

```
create external table hdfs_timedim
(
  timedimkey INT,
   ampmname STRING,
   begin15minutehourminutesecondname STRING,
    creationauditjobcontrolid INT,
   end15minutehourminutesecondname STRING,
    hourminutesecondampmname STRING,
   hournumber INT,
   lastupdateauditjobcontrolid INT,
    militaryhourminutesecondname STRING,
   militaryhournumber INT,
   minutenumber INT,
   slotname STRING, 
  slotnumber INT,
   sqltime string
)
row format delimited fields terminated by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
location '/xxx/timedim';
```

Comment: Seems to be an external table but there seem to need write perm on the directory above the data file to allow some move.

Comment: What server would the directory be on in a distributed system?